# jQuery 1.7.2: .on() works on one page and doesn't work on another

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I've the following piece of code which works on one page and doesn't work on another though html markup is the same on both pages:

#### JS

```
$("#books_list").on('click', '.load-more-books', function(event) {
  // Some stuffs
});
```

#### Html

```
<div id="book_list">
...
</div>
<a href="..." class="load-more-books">More books</a>
```

Even after entering JS code in Chrome Browser console events not bound.

Can anyone help me with this, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
Sultan

Comment: .load-more-books must be inside #books_list as you specify in the selector. This shouldn't work in either case really.

Comment: @JoakimJohansson: you should write this as an answer and not as a comment.

Comment: I better delete my answer or It will look as if I shamelessly stole @JoakimJohansson's comment. You beat me to it for 20 seconds though

Comment: @Alexander Hahaha, I'll write an answer if that's ok ;)

Comment: Thanks guys very much, sorry for that but mainly I sit on backend, so I didn't know `.load-more-books` should be descent to to its parent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The selector you specified means that `.load-more-books` needs to be a descendant of `#book_list` for this to work.

Answer (score -1):

Upgrade to jQuery 1.8.1 and see the results

Comment: That is not the problem here.